# How to create a scrollable radiobutton list in TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button, scrollbar

I am trying to create a scrollable list of radiobuttons in tkinter, but I'm not getting it to work. I have tried embedding my list of radiobuttons in various tkinter containers, but I get the same result, i.e., scrollbar doesn't work and the radiobutton list doesn't get cleared from the container (e.g., so I can replace it with a different list of radiobuttons). I have searched for how to do this and can't find anything. Is this possible?

Here's my sample application:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class CodeSampleForStackoverflow:
    def __init__(self, window):

        self.main_window = window
        self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(self.main_window, padding = '15 3 12 12')
        self.mainframe.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = "W, E, N, S")

        self.file_choice = tk.StringVar()
        self.contents_list = list()

        self.display_folder_btn = ttk.Button(self.mainframe, text = "Display list of choices", width = 20)
        self.display_folder_btn.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
        self.display_folder_btn.bind("<Button-1>", self.list_folder_contents)

        self.folder_contents_canvas = tk.Canvas(self.mainframe)
        self.scroll_y = tk.Scrollbar(self.folder_contents_canvas, orient="vertical")
        self.scroll_y.pack(fill = 'y', side = 'right')
        self.folder_contents_canvas.grid(row=2, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
        self.folder_contents_frame = tk.Text(self.folder_contents_canvas, height = 7, width = 50, yscrollcommand = self.scroll_y.set)
        self.folder_contents_frame.pack(side = "top", fill = "x", expand = False, padx = 20, pady = 20)


    def list_folder_contents(self, event):
        try:
            self.contents_list = ['A dictum nulla auctor id.', 'A porttitor diam iaculis quis.', 'Consectetur adipiscing elit.', \
                                  'Curabitur in ante iaculis', 'Finibus tincidunt nunc.', 'Fusce elit ligula', \
                                  'Id sollicitudin arcu semper sit amet.', 'Integer at sapien leo.', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', \
                                  'Luctus ligula suscipit', 'Nam vitae erat a dolor convallis', \
                                  'Praesent feugiat quam ac', 'Pretium diam.', 'Quisque accumsan vehicula dolor', \
                                  'Quisque eget arcu odio.', 'Sed ac elit id dui blandit dictum', 'Sed et eleifend leo.', \
                                  'Sed vestibulum fermentum augue', 'Suspendisse pharetra cursus lectus', 'Ultricies eget erat et', \
                                  'Vivamus id lorem mi.']
            contents_dict = dict()
            self.folder_contents_frame.delete(1.0, 'end')
            counter = 0
            for i in self.contents_list:
                contents_dict[str(counter+1)] = i
                counter+=1
            for (text, value) in contents_dict.items():
                #self.folder_contents_frame.insert(1.0, text+"\t"+value+"\n")
                ttk.Radiobutton(self.folder_contents_frame, text = value, variable = self.file_choice, value = text, style = "TRadiobutton").grid(column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = tk.W)
            self.scroll_y.config(command = self.folder_contents_frame.yview)

        except Exception as exc:
            print(exc)


#-----------------------------------------

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Scrollable radiobutton list')
    root.geometry("500x600")
    tabs = ttk.Notebook(root)
    tabs.pack(fill = "both")
    scrollable_radiobutton_list_frame = ttk.Frame(tabs)
    tabs.add(scrollable_radiobutton_list_frame, text = "Scrollable radiobutton list")
             
    my_checker = CodeSampleForStackoverflow(window = scrollable_radiobutton_list_frame)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you comment out the line in the list_folder_contents method that creates the radiobuttons and uncomment the line above it, you can see how I'd like it to behave, but with radiobuttons rather than plain text.

Edit: side question: If anyone knows why (in the text version) the items are being added in reverse order, I'd appreciate guidance there as well.

Thank you for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this is to create a scrollable frame class and use that. I have a scrollable frame class taken from SO (I can't remember which answer exactly) and modified for my needs which should work for your application.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class ScrollFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent) # create a frame (self)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")      # Canvas to scroll
        self.viewPort = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")     # This frame will hold the child widgets
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview) 
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)      # Attach scrollbar action to scroll of canvas

        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")       # Pack scrollbar to right - change as needed
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)     # Pack canvas to left and expand to fill - change as needed
        self.canvas_window = self.canvas.create_window(
            (0,0), 
            window=self.viewPort, 
            anchor="nw",            
            tags="self.viewPort",
            )       # Add view port frame to canvas

        self.viewPort.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.onCanvasConfigure)
        self.first = True
        self.onFrameConfigure(None) # Initial stretch on render

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    def onCanvasConfigure(self, event):
        '''Reset the canvas window to encompass inner frame when required'''
        canvas_width = event.width
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.canvas_window, width = canvas_width)

    def on_mousewheel(self, event):
        '''Allows the mousewheel to control the scrollbar'''
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")

    def bnd_mousewheel(self):
        '''Binds the mousewheel to the scrollbar'''
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self.on_mousewheel)

    def unbnd_mousewheel(self):
        '''Unbinds the mousewheel from the scrollbar'''
        self.canvas.unbind_all("<MouseWheel>")

    def delete_all(self):
        '''Removes all widgets from the viewPort, only works if grid was used'''
        children = self.viewPort.winfo_children()
        for child in children:
            child.grid_remove()

class CodeSampleForStackoverflow:
    def __init__(self, window):

        self.main_window = window
        self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(self.main_window, padding = '15 3 12 12')
        self.mainframe.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = "W, E, N, S")

        self.file_choice = tk.StringVar()
        self.contents_list = list()

        self.display_folder_btn = ttk.Button(self.mainframe, text = "Display list of choices", width = 20, command=self.list_folder_contents)
        self.display_folder_btn.pack(side="top")

        self.folder_contents_frame = ScrollFrame(self.mainframe)
        self.folder_contents_frame.pack(side = "top", fill = "x", expand = False, padx = 20, pady = 20)


    def list_folder_contents(self):
        try:
            self.contents_list = ['A dictum nulla auctor id.', 'A porttitor diam iaculis quis.', 'Consectetur adipiscing elit.', \
                                  'Curabitur in ante iaculis', 'Finibus tincidunt nunc.', 'Fusce elit ligula', \
                                  'Id sollicitudin arcu semper sit amet.', 'Integer at sapien leo.', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', \
                                  'Luctus ligula suscipit', 'Nam vitae erat a dolor convallis', \
                                  'Praesent feugiat quam ac', 'Pretium diam.', 'Quisque accumsan vehicula dolor', \
                                  'Quisque eget arcu odio.', 'Sed ac elit id dui blandit dictum', 'Sed et eleifend leo.', \
                                  'Sed vestibulum fermentum augue', 'Suspendisse pharetra cursus lectus', 'Ultricies eget erat et', \
                                  'Vivamus id lorem mi.']
            contents_dict = dict()
            self.folder_contents_frame.delete_all()
            counter = 0
            for i in self.contents_list:
                contents_dict[str(counter+1)] = i
                counter+=1
            for (text, value) in contents_dict.items():
                ttk.Radiobutton(self.folder_contents_frame.viewPort, text = value, variable = self.file_choice, value = text, style = "TRadiobutton").grid(column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = tk.W)

        except Exception as exc:
            print(exc)

#-----------------------------------------

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Scrollable radiobutton list')
    root.geometry("500x600")
    tabs = ttk.Notebook(root)
    tabs.pack(fill = "both")
    scrollable_radiobutton_list_frame = ttk.Frame(tabs)
    tabs.add(scrollable_radiobutton_list_frame, text = "Scrollable radiobutton list")
             
    my_checker = CodeSampleForStackoverflow(window = scrollable_radiobutton_list_frame)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This looks like it does exactly what I want it to do. Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: No worries, glad I could help

Comment: _"You shouldn't be using a Text widget as your scrollable container"_ - why do you say that? It actually works quite well for a scrollable container, especially if you are creating a single vertical stack of widgets.

Comment: @BryanOakley ah fair point, I've found it easier working with a frame, all of the applications I've needed have had more than a single vertical stack. Will edit it out of my answer